# Error Deployment on Azure

Tags: python, azure, deployment, setuptools, azure-web-app-service

Could you please help me with the following error? I am trying to deploy a web app to Azure and I encounter the following issue:

> Even if by requirements, a newer version of setuptools is installed,
>   the deployment fails with the error:"  RuntimeError: cryptography
>   requires setuptools 18.5 or newer, please upgrade to a newer version
>   of setuptools".

The whole log is as it follows:

> Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd" Handling python
>   deployment. Detected requirements.txt.  You can skip Python specific
>   steps with a .skipPythonDeployment file. Detecting Python runtime from
>   site configuration Detected python-3.4 Found compatible virtual
>   environment. Pip install requirements. Downloading/unpacking
>   setuptools>=18.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) Requirement
>   already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): Flask==0.12.1 in
>   d:\home\site\wwwroot\env\lib\site-packages (from -r requirements.txt
>   (line 2)) Downloading/unpacking azure-storage-file==1.1.0 (from -r
>   requirements.txt (line 3))   Downloading
>   azure_storage_file-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl Downloading/unpacking
>   azure-storage-common>=1.1.0,<1.2.0 (from azure-storage-file==1.1.0->-r
>   requirements.txt (line 3)) Downloading/unpacking
>   azure-storage-nspkg>=2.0.0 (from azure-storage-file==1.1.0->-r
>   requirements.txt (line 3))   Downloading
>   azure_storage_nspkg-3.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl Downloading/unpacking
>   azure-common>=1.1.5 (from azure-storage-file==1.1.0->-r
>   requirements.txt (line 3))   Downloading
>   azure_common-1.1.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl Downloading/unpacking
>   cryptography (from
>   azure-storage-common>=1.1.0,<1.2.0->azure-storage-file==1.1.0->-r
>   requirements.txt (line 3))   Running setup.py
>   (path:D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\cryptography\setup.py) egg_info
>   for package cryptography
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "", line 17, in 
>         File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\cryptography\setup.py", line 28, in 
>           "cryptography requires setuptools 18.5 or newer, please upgrade to a "
>       RuntimeError: cryptography requires setuptools 18.5 or newer, please upgrade to a newer version of setuptools
>       Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
>       Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 17, in    File
>   "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\cryptography\setup.py", line 28, in
>   
>       "cryptography requires setuptools 18.5 or newer, please upgrade to a " RuntimeError: cryptography requires setuptools 18.5 or newer,
>   please upgrade to a newer version of setuptools
>   ---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in
>   D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\build\cryptography Storing debug log for
>   failure in D:\home\pip\pip.log An error has occurred during web site
>   deployment. \r\nD:\Program Files
>   (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\73.10426.3381\bin\Scripts\starter.cmd
>
> ### "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade the python module `setuptools` installed on your target.

If you used python3 (it looks to be case from the log), run this command: `pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`

If you are still using python2 then this command `pip install --upgrade setuptools`.

If you do not have permission access then use the flag `--user`: `pip3 install --user --upgrade setuptools`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to OlivierM, installing Python packages in Azure App Services is little tricky using pip. It’s recommended to use wheels for installing Python dependencies.

Some packages may not install using pip when run on Azure. It may simply be that the package is not available on the Python Package Index. It could be that a compiler is required (a compiler is not available on the machine running the web app in Azure App Service).

Checkout the documentation on Troubleshooting - Package Installation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-python-configure#troubleshooting---package-installation